# Difference between single and double square brackets in autoconf

Tags: autoconf

So what is the difference between single and double square brackets in autoconf?

[Autoconf docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.64/html_node/Generic-Types.html) show following example:

```
AC_CHECK_TYPES([float_t], [], [], [[#include <math.h>]])
```

IMHO it also works with single brackets:

```
AC_CHECK_TYPES([float_t], [], [], [#include <math.h>])
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use `[[ ]]` for your macro argument, you can use `[` and `]` inside the macro argument as you please. If, on the other hand, you use `[]` for your macro argument, `[` and `]` retain their special autoconf/m4 meaning inside the macro argument.

The difference becomes obvious if the actual text in the macro argument contains brackets, e.g.

```
dnl Minimum working example configure.ac. To run:
dnl   touch Makefile.am && autoreconf -vis . && ./configure

AC_PREREQ([2.69])
AC_INIT([stackoverflow53609622], [0.0.1], [bugs@example.com])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall -Werror foreign])

AC_PROG_CC

AC_MSG_CHECKING([compile example 1])
AC_COMPILE_IFELSE([AC_LANG_SOURCE([[
const char hw[] = "Hello, World\n";
const char hs[] = "Hello, Stackoverflow\n";
]])], [AC_MSG_RESULT([yes])], [AC_MSG_RESULT([no])])

AC_MSG_CHECKING([compile example 2])
AC_COMPILE_IFELSE([AC_LANG_SOURCE([
const char hw[[]] = "Hello, World\n";
const char hs[[]] = "Hello, Stackoverflow\n";
])], [AC_MSG_RESULT([yes])], [AC_MSG_RESULT([no])])

AC_MSG_CHECKING([compile example 3])
AC_COMPILE_IFELSE([AC_LANG_SOURCE([
const char hw[] = "Hello, World\n";
const char hs[] = "Hello, Stackoverflow\n";
])], [AC_MSG_RESULT([yes])], [AC_MSG_RESULT([no])])

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

Both examples 1 and 2 will test compile the C program

```
const char hw[] = "Hello, World\n";
const char hs[] = "Hello, Stackoverflow\n";
```

but example 3 will test compile the broken C program

```
const char hw = "Hello, World\n";
const char hs = "Hello, Stackoverflow\n";
```

which will not compile (see `config.log` for the compiler error messages).

If you put unbalanced brackets into the macro argument text, however, `m4` will still become really confused about where macro arguments begin or end. AFAIK, the only way around that is to use quadrigraphs (`@<:@` for `[` and `@:>@` for `]`):

```
AC_MSG_CHECKING([compile example 4])
AC_COMPILE_IFELSE([AC_LANG_SOURCE([[
const char hw[] = "Hello, World @<:@-:\n";
const char hs[] = "Hello, Stackoverflow\n";
]])], [AC_MSG_RESULT([yes])], [AC_MSG_RESULT([no])])

AC_MSG_CHECKING([compile example 5])
AC_COMPILE_IFELSE([AC_LANG_SOURCE([[
const char hw[] = "Hello, World :-@:>@\n";
const char hs[] = "Hello, Stackoverflow\n";
]])], [AC_MSG_RESULT([yes])], [AC_MSG_RESULT([no])])
```

The following will fail either at `autoreconf` or at `configure` time which indicates that something is going very wrong and you should steer very clear from that.

```
AC_MSG_CHECKING([compile example 6])
AC_COMPILE_IFELSE([AC_LANG_SOURCE([[
const char hw[] = "Hello, World :-[\n";
const char hs[] = "Hello, Stackoverflow\n";
]])], [AC_MSG_RESULT([yes])], [AC_MSG_RESULT([no])])

AC_MSG_CHECKING([compile example 7])
AC_COMPILE_IFELSE([AC_LANG_SOURCE([[
const char hw[] = "Hello, World :-]\n";
const char hs[] = "Hello, Stackoverflow\n";
]])], [AC_MSG_RESULT([yes])], [AC_MSG_RESULT([no])])
```

For further reading, you can start at https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/M4-Quotation.html and dig deeper from there.